# Extracting data from swift files iOS

Tags: file-handling

I want to extract some particular lines of code from my swift files (n number of files) and get that data in a textfile .

For example

I have many code like this

self.lblName.title = StringFiles.getvalueforKey("title")

I want to extract the lines which consist of ".title" , so that I can check whether all the label text values are assigned with some text .

I'm not experienced with file handling concepts so I'm looking for this .

Comment: You want to do a swift script that extract all lines with a regex `.*\.title =`? Or is the XCode search enough for that?

Comment: I can't go with Xcode search , I want to copy all the lines that have .title and paste that in a new text file

Comment: This question is not about programming but rather about using grep or a text editor.